# mongodb - how to query collection and document

Tags: mongodb

So say I have a collection of documents. Each document contains a primary and secondary address such as...

```
{
  primaryAddress: "94-111",
  secondaryAddress: "94-111"
}
```

What I want to do is, query for a primary address that has a primary address of "94-111" but exclude all results where the primaryAddress is equal to the secondaryAddress.

I tried the following with no luck.

```
db.address.find({primaryAddress:"94-111", secondaryAddress: {$ne this.primaryAddress}})
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare two fields within a document, use the aggregation framework:

```
db.addresses.aggregate({
  $project: {
      primaryAddress: '$primaryAddress',
      secondaryAddress: '$secondaryAddress',
      eq: {$eq: ['$primaryAddress', '$secondaryAddress']}
  }
}, {
    $match: {eq: false}
})
```

The `$project` stage of the pipeline carries the primary and secondary addresses into the next stage, and it adds a field, `eq`, which is `true` if the fields are equal and `false` otherwise.

The `$match` stage gets the documents processed by the first stage, and filters out those where `eq` is `true`.

This aggregation pipeline will be much much faster than a `$where` clause, which executes Javascript on the server for each document.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
db.address.find( 
  { $where: "this.primaryAddress == '94-111' &&
             this.primaryAddress != this.secondaryAddress" } );
```

which should be equivalent to

```
db.address.find( 
  { $where: "this.primaryAddress == '94-111' &&
             this.secondaryAddress != '94-111'" } );
```

You can drop the where operator if you like, see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where).

Answer (score 0):

If you want documents where primaryAddress = "94-111" AND secondaryAddress <> "94-111", try this:

```
db.address.find({primaryAddress:"94-111", secondaryAddress: {$ne: "94-111"}})
```

If you want documents where primaryAddress <> secondaryAddress, see @Jesse's solution